# Adding a custom font to a paragraph in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

My goal is to add a custom font to a paragraph using iTextSharp however it does not seem to work, I have tried with both `.ttf` and `.otf` font types however neither worked.

My code:

```
var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(378, 576);
Document document = new Document(pgSize);

BaseFont customfont = BaseFont.CreateFont("Azonix.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font azonix = new iTextSharp.text.Font(customfont, 12);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("someFile.pdf", FileMode.Create));

document.Open();

Paragraph p = new Paragraph("example paragraph");
p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
p.Font = azonix;

document.Add(p);
document.Close();
```

The output of the PDF file uses the default font instead of the [azonix font](https://www.dafont.com/azonix.font).
The font is also inside of the same directory as the executable as shown in the picture:

[image: Picture]

**Other information:**

- **Windows 10 Pro**
- **.NET Framework 4.7.2**
- **Windows Forms Application**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first add text to the paragraph and,  thereafter, set the font:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("example paragraph");
...
p.Font = azonix;
```

To have the font applied to the text, though, set the font together with the text:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("example paragraph", azonix);
```

or before it:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
...
p.Font = azonix;
p.Add("example paragraph");
```